# ms crm 2011 quote start recalculate with javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have copied a quote with all quotedetails. Is it possible to start the recalculate process
with javascript? How can I do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the window to get the updated quote totals:

`window.location.reload(true)`